# Why my collator node produce only #1 block and not finalize it?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, collator

I am trying to running collator node by using [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/), I have secured testnet and everything is configured by my side but the issue is just `#1` block produce but it is not finalizing. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

[log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NDIgBkrjaBMdMnyI6wplY9-zIJm8IGxC/view?usp=drive_link)

```
aca707cb07750275f47ff8e939ba pov_hash=0xb442d6f6682fead92dc844caa0b9ac74ecf7a39c5fe61c55eb51b59a3e192967 traceID=171825202696515333740378575547046500615
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWCQnDeELzhGBrc6zmsuTT6wkaquqCKyVc62GLCQptDph4 from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWQ5vi4RDbNk7yomsmbK7T29qCHn5odVgSsqXBEVoxKjgc from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWCH6iag326rbQoudrz7uu3XrZPZZo2caiQA732i12JnRa from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWA8Axi4Kpco6C23oi5UmaNXNf8xWefhRCe3dUxLLB7yGq from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWDNh3a8CkZbtNonPiEpjjnrew9jASbMWq5EJ3LUqkF1DQ from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWKAaBLGjMbG5WmndYHMTYB2aeuYcGVvQnpHqCZeDGVuY8 from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWDHNutH9RQNC945HHjokYK3cbHzjQBJTzi7fYQUbkS9uN from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWFLjtSmQBj6XtqPGMtKyNRAoZ1HK6iaVwhUTAncee8DZE from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWBhsJ9jn7ydL6uc91BRFYCqZp1cxfcs3H5VjhvVnUdm5i from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWQjdm56qV6NmgFm9Ao2tQPhc8sNJe9LSSoBVNc8eNKF3E from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:16.659  WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Relaychain] Trying to remove unknown reserved node 12D3KooWPc7TGVfwXfw8Sh9opDwQZNXcTiWL4FCuFFZccZfEcQ1a from SetId(3).    
2024-03-29 18:38:17.415  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (9 peers), best: #552257 (0x59db…74be), finalized #552255 (0xff89…2819), ⬇ 21.0kiB/s ⬆ 28.8kiB/s    
2024-03-29 18:38:17.589  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #1 (0x17e1…956f), finalized #0 (0xf953…4cee), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2024-03-29 18:38:18.465  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #552258 (0xf0bd…9854)    
2024-03-29 18:38:22.420  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (9 peers), best: #552258 (0xf0bd…9854), finalized #552256 (0xdb0c…d2f4), ⬇ 23.7kiB/s ⬆ 24.8kiB/s    
2024-03-29 18:38:22.595  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #1 (0x17e1…956f), finalized #0 (0xf953…4cee), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.399  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #552259 (0x89c5…8219)    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.401  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xf953cea773de03ece1590192daad3cb02a0fdb2cf140d4482a4b69cfdf424cee    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.402 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker basic-authorship: [Parachain] Attempting to push transactions from the pool.    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.402 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker basic-authorship: [Parachain] Pool status: PoolStatus { ready: 0, ready_bytes: 0, future: 0, future_bytes: 0 }    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.402 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker basic-authorship: [Parachain] No more transactions, proceeding with proposing.    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.403  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (2 ms) [hash: 0x88261469bd89fbf8d45538e2dbb5cacc80e3a1c8c34a7e759eb76b82934773b6; parent_hash: 0xf953…4cee; extrinsics (2): [0x785e…5feb, 0xd184…ea39]    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.406  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0xf1aa3799046d5986179e0546da4db783ac5faf4b19660f26c3167771be298bcc, previously 0x88261469bd89fbf8d45538e2dbb5cacc80e3a1c8c34a7e759eb76b82934773b6.
2024-03-29 18:38:24.408  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #1 (0xf1aa…8bcc)    
2024-03-29 18:38:24.408  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.2197265625kb, extrinsics: 3.5029296875kb, storage_proof: 2.6513671875kb }
2024-03-29 18:38:24.408  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura::cumulus: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 5.490234375kb
```